# Force Field Limitation in Drafts - Front End Form

Tags: entries, field, draft

I'm not sure if this is a two part question yet. I need to enforce field limitations (specifically, character limits for plain text fields) when working with drafts. In the CP, I discovered that drafts ignore all limitations related to character length and only throw errors when attempting to publish the draft.

I'm assuming that enforcing the draft field limitations in the CP will also apply to front end entries that are saved as drafts as well. If not, this is what I'm doing:

I have a front end form for user created entries. Everything has been working correctly with the exception of field limitations (users submit draft revisions until published by an admin).

Any idea how to force field limitations for a draft?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom field validation won't run for disabled entries or for drafts, regardless of whether it's a front-end request or a CP request.

There is an [Always Validate](https://github.com/mmikkel/AlwaysValidate-Craft) plugin that changes that behavior for disabled entries/categories.  It could pretty easily be modified to do that for drafts as well.